# JW Player does not repeat video

Tags: jquery, html, dreamweaver, jwplayer, flv

JW player doesn't play video in loop (repeat video) although required Flags has been mentioned.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
    'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
    'file': 'vidflv.flv',
    'controlbar': 'bottom',
    'width': '554',
    'height': '370',
'autostart' : true,
  'autoplay' : true
  'repeat' : true

  });
</script>
```

Comment: you missed a , after 'autoplay' : true

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using JW5 here.

So change:

```
'repeat' : true
```

To:

```
'repeat' : 'always'
```

Comment: This is from 3 years ago.

Comment: yes, but I was trying for JW player 5 so I thought it should work

Comment: anyways I upgraded to 7

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for loop JWPlayer without extra requests or tracking (Advertisement modes), I found that you can manually add `loop` attribute to the video element. In this case, it should work like HTML looped video, but JWPlayer functionality is working well